# Inserting Word and Powerpoint documents in LaTeX

Tags: appendix

I am writing my thesis in LaTeX. However, I already made some booklets and slides in Microsoft Word and PowerPoint. These documents have to be added as appendices to my thesis in LaTeX. They both are not just plain text and I would like to have the same lay-out in the appendices as the original documents. How could I do this?

```
\begin{figure} [h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{PublicTemplate/appendices/book page 3.pdf}
    \caption{Book page 3}
    \label{fig: booklet}
\end{figure}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Convert your Word/Powerpoint documents to PDF files, then include these PDFs to your LaTeX file.

Comment: I tried, but I only got the first page then and there is a it includes the title of the document (e.g. 'page 7.pdf') above the document which I do not like

Comment: Use `pdfpages` not `graphicx` to include PDF files like this.

Comment: Could you explain how to do this? Is that a package?

Comment: They are packages and come with manuals.  The big question is how you want them to appear.  Do you want to shrink them, pack several pages per page, or maintain your current text area and header/footer?

Comment: Does this also work for Overleaf? Because I downloaded it, but I am lost now

Answer (score 2):

Alan Munn's comment is detailed below

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
    \usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages={3-4}]{pdfpages.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Compile with `pdflatex` after having downloaded the pdfpages manual called `pdfpages.pdf`. The above code includes pages 3 and 4 of the manual.

Comment: On an up-to-date TeXLive or MikTeX one can use `example-image-duck` or `example-image-duck-portrait`. Each of those files has 128 pages of lovely ducks! No need to download some shady manual :)

Comment: @Skillmon Agreed... but this was a soft way to say RTFM.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of how you can use `pdfpages`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\includepdf{Test2.pdf}
\lipsum[6-10]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I just added every page separately, but is it also possible to do this at once? And more important, is it possible to still get the normal foot notes (e.g. title of the thesis and the page numbers), because these are not shown right now?